# Exception when calling overloaded static method using JSR223

Tags: javascript, nashorn, jsr223, openhab

I'm trying to implement a rule for openHAB (http://www.openhab.org/) in Javascript using JSR223 (https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/Jsr223-Script-Engine).

Anyone having a suggestion of the root cause of following exception? Remark that both instances passed as argument implement the interfaces used as parameters in the method declaration.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: None of the fixed arity signatures [(org.openhab.core.items.Item, org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant)] of method org.openhab.core.persistence.extensions.PersistenceExtensions.changedSince match the argument types [org.openhab.core.items.GroupItem, org.joda.time.DateTime]
        at jdk.nashorn.javaadapters.java.util.function.Consumer.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.L:13(<eval>:14) ~[na:na]
        at org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.shared.Rule$$NashornJavaAdapter.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.engine.RuleExecutionRunnable.run(RuleExecutionRunnable.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Following is the implemented script:

```
'use strict';

load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
importPackage(org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.shared);
importPackage(org.joda.time);
importPackage(org.joda.time.base);


var autoOffRule = new org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.shared.Rule() {
    getEventTrigger: function() {
        return [
            new org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.shared.TimerTrigger("* * * * * ?")
        ];
    }, 
    execute: function(event) {
        for each(var item in ItemRegistry.getItems()) {
            if (item.getState() == org.openhab.core.library.types.OnOffType.ON) {
                var dateTime = org.joda.time.DateTime.now().withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.seconds(), -5);

                if (!(org.openhab.core.persistence.extensions.PersistenceExtensions.class.static.changedSince(item, var dateTime))) {
                    print("Auto-off for " + item.getName())
                }
            }            
        }
    }
};

function getRules() {
    return new org.openhab.core.jsr223.internal.shared.RuleSet([ autoOffRule ]);
}
```

The called method is overloaded and has following signatures:

```
org.openhab.core.persistence.extensions.PersistenceExtensions#changedSince(org.openhab.core.items.Item, org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant)
org.openhab.core.persistence.extensions.PersistenceExtensions#changedSince(org.openhab.core.items.Item, org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant, java.lang.String)
```

Tested and failing both on jdk1.8.0_31 and jdk1.8.0_65. Bumped into a more or less a similar exception having a rule implemented in Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm a necromantic when answering this question but I stumbled upon it and couldn't resist.

The error message is clear: You try to invoke the Java Method [`org.openhab.core.persistence.extensions.PersistenceExtensions.changedSince(org.openhab.core.items.Item, org.joda.time.DateTime)`](https://github.com/carlossg/openhab/blob/master/bundles/core/org.openhab.core.persistence/src/main/java/org/openhab/core/persistence/extensions/PersistenceExtensions.java#L145) with a `GroupItem`.

[Which is interesting since a `GroupItem` extends the `GenericItem` which implements the `Item` Interface](https://github.com/carlossg/openhab/tree/master/bundles/core/org.openhab.core/src/main/java/org/openhab/core/items) and therefore should match the method signature.

With `for each(var item in ItemRegistry.getItems()) {` you get all items from your OpenHab Item Definition including all groups. You probably only want the real items. Try `if (! item.members )` to filter all groups.